# Borel-Cantelli difficult summation

Tags: probability

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be i.i.d. random variables with $P\{X_k=1\}=p$ and $P\{X_k=0\}=1-p$. Let
$$
R_n:=\sup\{k \geq 0 : X_n=X_{n+1}=\cdots=X_{n+k-1}=1\}.
$$
That is: $R_n$ is the length of the run of consecutive $1$'s that starts at $n$. (If $X_n=0$, then set $R_n=0$.) Prove that
$$
P\left\{ \limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{R_n}{\log n}=\left|\log p\right|^{-1} \right\}=1.
$$
*HINT: For a fixed parameter $\alpha>0$, let*
$$
B_n^{(\alpha)}:=\{R_n>\alpha\log n/\left|\log p\right|\}.
$$
*If $\alpha>1$, then by the first Borel-Cantelli Lemma and direct computation, only finitely many of the $B_n^{(\alpha)}$'s occur a.s. If $\alpha\leq1$, then from the previous exercise it follows that a.s. infinitely many of the $B_n^{(\alpha)}$'s occur.*

I see that if we can show that for $\alpha>1$ finitely many of these $B_n^{(\alpha)}$ events occur, and and for $\alpha\leq1$ infinitely many of these $B_n^{(\alpha)}$ events occur, then we have answered the question. So far I have managed to show using a previous question that this is the case for $\alpha\leq1$. So my confusion now lies in trying to prove that this is true for $\alpha>1$. So now let $\alpha>1$. I want to somehow show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(B_n^{(\alpha)})<\infty$ so I can use the Borel-Cantelli lemma to show that this event happens finitely often, thus answering the question. I believe that
$$
P\bigl\{B_n^{(\alpha)}\bigr\} = p^{\left\lceil \frac{\alpha\log n}{\left|\log p\right|} \right\rceil}\leq p^{\frac{\alpha\log n}{\left|\log p\right|}+1}.
$$
But I am suspicious that this is wrong because when it seems too complicated when it then comes to summing
$$
p\sum_{n=1}^\infty p^{\frac{\alpha\log n}{\left|\log p\right|}}.
$$
Is this a sum I should be able to work out, or am I misunderstanding something else? If I am expected to be able work out this sum, could anybody help me do this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What are your $X_n$'s? Are they i.i.d. and $\operatorname{Ber}(p)$? It would be nice if you can clarify this so we can better understand your approach!

Comment: Oh yes sorry forgot to put that in! I'll do it now

Comment: A minor issue: You would have $$p^{\left\lceil \frac{\alpha\log n}{\left|\log p\right|} \right\rceil}\leq p^{\frac{\alpha\log n}{\left|\log p\right|}}$$ instead, because $x\mapsto p^x$ is decreasing in $x$ and $x \leq \lceil x \rceil$. Anyway, you are almost good to go because we have $$p^{\frac{\alpha\log n}{\left|\log p\right|}} = p^{-\alpha \log_p n} = n^{-\alpha}. $$

Comment: Ahhh I see so the summation was not as complicated as I thought! Thanks very much for your help and corrections.

Comment: Glad it helped! I am pretty sure you could also have come up with this after some break and with a cup of coffee :)